# How to dynamically add radio buttons with two extra buttons android

Tags: android, radio-button

I want to create the following view:

[image]

For above picture, I declared a vertical radio group in xml, and rows were added at run time. In a single radio button , i want to add two other buttons,as shown in picture,
This code is to add address (radio buttons) to radiogroup.

```
 private void add_to_address_list() {
        for (int i = 0; i < addresses_list.size(); i++) {
            RadioButton rdbtn = new RadioButton(this);
            Log.d("mytag", "id : " + i + "name :" + i);
             addresses_list.get(i).getUser_line2());
            String line1 = addresses_list.get(i).getUser_line1();
            String line2 = addresses_list.get(i).getUser_line2();
            String line3 = addresses_list.get(i).getGoogle_line1();
            rdbtn.setId(i);
            rdbtn.setText(Html.fromHtml("<font color=black size=3em>" +line1+"<br>"+line2+"<br></font>" +"<font color=grey size=3em>"+ line3+"</font><br>"));
            ((ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.address_radio_group)).addView(rdbtn);
        }

    }
```

How can i add two other buttons, one is for delete the address and another is for edit address, is it possible ? or can i go with simple list view?

if i use listview to display it, is it possible to select one only. i think it may possible with check boxes. suggest any correct method. pleas help me.Thanks.

Comment: You can select any child items using listview. so i prefer you to use listview here

Comment: If you want the same then ..
1. You can use custom list adapter.
2. Make a custom list row layout with radio button, Address line text     
   view, and one menu button on top right corner of list row.
3. set the onClickListener on menu button of table row.. set Context
   menu on it.
add items to context menu <Edit,Delete>